# How get dates on week day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I wanted to ask about how to get date on weekday

[image]

`green is weekday`

`red is sunday`

so when i input sql command it (like 27) when year 2012
it  will show date 2012-07-2 until 2012-07-08

Comment: yes. For database. I want to calculate  production day every week

Comment: Yes i must input range of week to database. SQl-server actualy. Thanks

Comment: And the output is 7 rows representing the days of that week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query uses a single parameter `@weekno` as input and returns the 7 days in that week, taking Monday as the first day of week. The definition of WeekNo **does not** follow SQL Server's `DatePart(Week)` because that depends on @@Datefirst.  This doesn't.

The `dateadd..` line is an expression that returns the first Monday of the year.  I got it from [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1161577-391-2.aspx#bm1162727).  The line above it just adds the weeks to it and 0-6 to create 7 days.  To verify this is correct for any year, change `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the query to a date, such as `20180708`.  FYI, 1-Jan-2018 is a Monday.

```
declare @weekno int = 27;
select
    (@weekno-1)*7+v.num+
    dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,0,dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),6))/7)*7,0)
from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6))v(num)
order by num

-- results
July, 02 2012 00:00:00+0000
July, 03 2012 00:00:00+0000
July, 04 2012 00:00:00+0000
July, 05 2012 00:00:00+0000
July, 06 2012 00:00:00+0000
July, 07 2012 00:00:00+0000
July, 08 2012 00:00:00+0000
```

Comment: Yes, if you dont mind can i ask where i must put @weekno .Thanks

Comment: Seconding that, there is no `@weekno` in the query proper.

Comment: @Andriy I shouldn't type while hungry and make mistakes :)